# Colum Group in Report Viewer

Tags: reportviewer

I have a column group nested in row groups. I want for the column group to only show a row for each item in the row group.

[image: Report]

[image: Groups]
[image]

Is there any way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

I resolved this by adding a row group inside the column group. I grouped the Results column using row group and it worked!